# FileStream Seek/ReadByte seems to reverse byte order of file

Tags: c#, unicode, stream, unicode-string

I don't understand the results i'm getting from the hacked about code below, can someone explain. only happens when reading a **UNICODE** encoded text file.

```
fs = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

// read from start
byte[] lne = new byte[100];
int actual = fs.Read(lne, 0, lne.Length);
string line = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(lne, 0, actual); // ok readable stuff as expected
string line1 = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(lne, 0, actual); // fail as expected

// move down into the file
fs.Seek(-150, SeekOrigin.End);
fs.ReadByte(); // take this out, works ok!

lne = new byte[100];
actual = fs.Read(lne, 0, lne.Length);
line = encoding.GetString(lne, 0, actual); // fail non readable stuff - NOT EXPECTED
line1 = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(lne, 0, actual); // SUCCESS, readable - huh!
```

Obviously the code isn't "real world" , its just a breakdown of what my real code is doing.

after the first Encoding.Unicode.GetString I can see good readable data in the variable 'line', and crappy data in 'line1' as expected.

After the second Encoding.Unicode.GetString I see complete crap (japenese/chinese i don't know), but line1 now contains readable data thats come from the file.

If I take out the ReadByte everything works as expected.

Anyone any ideas why this is happening.

TIA.

Comment: Consider using a [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unicode strings are 2 bytes, and for ASCII strings looks like

```
0x41, 0, 0x42, 0, 0x43, 0 ...  // {ASCII code for A}, 0,...
```

So if you read bytes in opposite order (`BigEndianUnicode`) you get nonsense characters. String above read as `0x4100, 0x4200, 0x4300 ...` instead of `0x0041,...`

Similar happens when you start reading at odd offset (your seeking from end of file code) - bytes with ASCII text look like:

```
0, 0x41, 0, 0x42, 0, 0x43 ...
```

which are read as `0x4100, 0x4200, 0x4300...`

`ReadByte` takes out first 0 so you are reading from beginning of character, not the middle of it and sequence become valid ASCII-only Unicode string (with potentially invalid last character:

```
0x41, 0, 0x42, 0, 0x43,...
```

Comment: Yeah i thought that was the problem, no real fix either, I just found it strange that the second BigEndianUnicode.getstring produced valid readable data. but then thinking about it, it would I guess becuase if i've read into the "middle" of a uncode string, the next 2 bytes would appear reversed.

Comment: @push22 note that second `BigEndianUnicode.GetString` would show mess for non-ASCII characters as it will start picking halves from 2 characters: `0x41, 0x01, 0x42, 0x2` starting from second byte will endup with `0x0142` instead of either `0x0141` or `0x0242`.

Answer (score 2):

You are moving to the end of the stream minus 100 bytes. Then you read a byte (which takes you to the end of the stream minus 99 bytes) and afterwards are you trying to read 100 bytes. That takes you one byte outside the stream.

Comment: ta, but that doesn't explain why there's crap in the first line and good data in the second - on the second read, I've edited the code to take away the 100/99 discrepancy away.